# join 2 table in mysql which one of the table has more many rows and sum it

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables

TAble A:

```
mydate      myid  amount
========================
2016-03-14     5    100
```

table B:

```
mydate      myid  amount
========================
2016-03-14     5    90   
2016-03-15     2     50
2016-03-16     1     80
```

i want to join table A and table B to a new display result like this:

```
mydate      myid  amount
========================
2016-03-14     5    190   
2016-03-15     2     50
2016-03-16     1     80
```

pls help

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UNION ALL` to "combine" both tables and then aggregate:

```
SELECT mydate, myid, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM (SELECT mydate, myid, amount
      FROM table_A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT mydate, myid, amount
      FROM table_B) AS sub
GROUP BY mydate, myid
ORDER BY mydate;
```

Comment: hello i try to modif like this SELECT tanggal, kodetb,  angka1+angka2-angka3
FROM (SELECT tanggal, kodetb, angka as angka1
      FROM temp_utama1_stafsda utm1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT tanggal, kodetb, angka as angka2
      FROM temp_utama2_stafsda utm2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT tanggal, kodetb, angka as angka3
      FROM temp_utama3_stafsda utm3
     ) AS sub

where DATE_FORMAT(tanggal ,'%Y-%m-%d')=DATE_FORMAT('2016-03-14' ,'%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY tanggal, kodetb why it doesnt work with 3 tables

Comment: @mlms133 [“chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) Please ask new question with your real data and http://sqlfiddle.com demo